# rbindlist: NA into date-time column

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

I am trying to build a function to insert a row of `NA`s into a data.table. I am using `rbindlist` in this way to accomplish it, where `x` is a `data.table`:

```
rbindlist(
  list(
    x,
    as.list(rep(NA, ncol(x)))
  )
)
```

I am encountering an issue whereby `POSIXct` columns cannot be bound with `NA` values, as in:

```
x <- data.table(
  a=c(1,2),
  t=c(Sys.time(), Sys.time()+100)
)

rbindlist(
  list(
    x,
    as.list(rep(NA, ncol(x)))
  )
)
```

this results for me in the following error:

```
    Error in rbindlist(list(x, as.list(rep(NA, ncol(x))))) : 
  Class attributes at column 2 of input list at position 2 does not match with column 2 of input list at position 1. Coercion of objects of class 'factor' alone is handled internally by rbind/rbindlist at the moment.
```

So it not able to bind the `NA` I supplied with the `POSIXct` column `x$t`.

**Question: how can I bind a single-row `data.table` of all `NA` values to a `data.table` with a `POSIXct`-type column?**

I have tried the following, which resulted in the same error:

```
rbindlist(
  list(
    x,
    as.list(c(NA, as.POSIXct(NA)))
  )
)
```

Of interest: calling the following on the original `data.table`

```
x[2, t:=NA]
x[2, a:=NA]
```

Returns:

```
    a                   t
1:  1 2019-04-04 12:38:57
2: NA                <NA>
```

Comment: please add information about version of data.table package

Comment: `packageVersion("data.table") #[1] ‘1.10.4.3’`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(
  a=c(1,2),
  t=c(Sys.time(), Sys.time()+100)
)

x[c(1:.N, NA)]

#     a                   t
# 1:  1 2019-04-04 13:01:34
# 2:  2 2019-04-04 13:03:14
# 3: NA                <NA>

# or

rbind(x, x[NA])
```

In base R, you would use `NA_integer_` for the latter, but data.table treats NA the same way for convenience. You can see the special treatment, eg, with `x[(NA)]`. This is documented in `vignette("datatable-faq")`:

> **2.17 What are the smaller syntax differences between data.frame and data.table**
>
> [...]
>
> `DT[NA]` returns 1 row of `NA`, but `DF[NA]` returns an entire copy of
>   `DF` containing `NA` throughout. The symbol `NA` is type `logical` in
>   R and is therefore recycled by `[.data.frame`. The user's intention
>   was probably `DF[NA_integer_]`. `[.data.table` diverts to this
>   probable intention automatically, for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this-

```
library(data.table)
> a <- copy(x)[1]
> a[a] <- NA
> rbind(x,a)
    a                   t
1:  1 2019-04-04 12:54:47
2:  2 2019-04-04 12:56:27
3: NA                <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Also note** that you can run into this issue with **data.table outer merges** (All = TRUE)

```
library(data.table)

dtx <- data.table(id = 1, z2 = 2, z3 = as.Date("2023-07-31")) 
dty <- data.table(id = c(1, 2), z2 = c(2, 2))

# this works fine 
merge(dtx, dty, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
# this merge will break because it tries to add an NA under column z3
merge(dtx, dty, by = "id", all.y = TRUE)
```

**Proposed Solution, either:**

1. Remove any Date columns
2. Make sure Date column is in both data.tables and include the column in the merge key.

See as follow for solution #2:

```
dtx <- data.table(id = 1, z2 = 2, z3 = as.Date("2023-07-31"))
dty <- data.table(id = c(1, 2), z2 = c(2, 2), z3 = c(as.Date("2023-07-31"), as.Date("2023-08-01")))

# this works fine
merge(dtx, dty, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
# this works fine
merge(dtx, dty, by = c("id", "z3"), all.y = TRUE)
```